# Problemas para convertir un archivo.ui a archivo.py

Tags: python, interfaz, qt-designer

intento convertir un archivo.ui a archivo.py con:

```
pyuic5 BarraU.ui > BarraUIG.py
```

Pero tengo el siguiente error:

```
pyuic5 : El término 'pyuic5' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el 
nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ pyuic5 BarraU.ui > BarraUIG.py
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyuic5:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

El archivo lo hice con Qt Designer

Comment: pues no lo tienes  en el PATH, puedes agregarlo o puedes poner la ruta completa de donde se encuentra `pyuic5`

Comment: Te refieres al PATH de variables de entorno de windows?

Comment: a ese mismo....

Comment: Lo eh agregado y sigo con el mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes instalar el script pyuic5 que viene incluído en el paquete `pyqt5-tools`

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

Luego no te olvides de añadir al PATH tu carpeta de scripts, usualmente en:

```
C:\Users\<tuusuario>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python<version>\Scripts
```

Deberás **reiniciar** tu máquina luego de hacer este cambio, para que surta efecto.

Luego intenta ejecutar el comando nuevamente

```
pyuic5 -x tudibujo.ui -o tuarchivo.py
```

Answer (score 0):

si no te funciono, entonces en la carpeta:

`C:\Users\<tuusuario>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python<version>\Scripts`

veras varios `pip*.exe`, corre el la ultima versión en mi caso fue el `pip3.11.exe`:

`pip3.11 install pyqt5-tools`

cuando termine en esa carpeta veras que agrego varios archivos, entre ellas estará el `pyuic5.exe` y vuelve a ejecutar el:

`pyuic5 -x tudibujo.ui -o tuarchivo.py`